# Subtracting one column from multiple other columns

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, subtraction

I have an array of 7 columns and I'm trying to subtract the first column from all the other columns. Right now my code looks like this:

```
a  = (q[:,0]-q[:,1])**2
a1 = (q[:,0]-q[:,2])**2
a2 = (q[:,0]-q[:,3])**2
a3 = (q[:,0]-q[:,4])**2
a4 = (q[:,0]-q[:,5])**2
a5 = (q[:,0]-q[:,6])**2
```

This works well except that I'm trying to do this for many files and it is incredibly inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to write this same code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to subtract the first column *from* all other columns, you can do

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(40).reshape(8, 5) #sample data
y = (x - x[:,0,None])**2
```

The `x[:,0,None]` represents the first column.  If you just try `x - x[:,0]`, numpy can't broadcast the shapes together ((8, 5) and (8,) in this case).  Adding the `x[:,0,None]` (or `x[:,0,np.newaxis]`) makes the second shape (8, 1) and numpy can broadcast the two together.

Comment: can you show how to do this on a pandas dataframe? And can i write the result of the subtraction to a new column. I want to be able to compare the subtractions and find %difference.

Comment: @MurtazaHaji I would look at the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) or open a new question.  But pretty sure you could probably just do `df["new_column"] = df - df["col_of_interest"]`.